# uid ... does not have android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS

Tags: android, security, notifications

Since Android 4.3 I receive following stacktraces:

```
[STACKTRACE] => java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10140 does not have android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
    ...
```

The exception is thrown at the following line:

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());
```

I tried the new resticted user feature of Android 4.3, lauched my app under this user which showed a notification, without any problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you had any solution?

Comment: No, but the problem is no longer occurred

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue on the current Android release. Here is some more information for follow up: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58043

It has been fixed but not yet released.